# Fix VPN DNS Leak on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openvpn

When using Cyberghost through OpenVPN, my computer still uses the DNS settings from my router (in this case, Google Public DNS). I was able to use OpenVPN without DNS leaks on Ubuntu 15.04.

Following this article: http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/09/how-to-fix-openvpn-dns-leak-in-linux.html

I don't have a DNS leak if I connect to my VPN via terminal. But if I connect via Network Manager, I still have a DNS leak.

Is there a known way to fix this, or is it a bug with Network Manager? If I can't fix it, can my ISP still track me if I'm not using their DNS servers?

If it helps, here's my OpenVPN configuration:

```
client
remote 4-us.cg-dialup.net 443
dev tun 
proto udp
auth-user-pass


resolv-retry infinite 
redirect-gateway def1
persist-key
persist-tun
nobind
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth MD5
ping 5
ping-exit 60
ping-timer-rem
explicit-exit-notify 2
script-security 2
remote-cert-tls server
route-delay 5
tun-mtu 1500 
fragment 1300
mssfix 1300
verb 4
comp-lzo


ca ca.crt

cert client.crt

key client.key

script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Comment: How often do you use your VPN? You could set your gateway to be a route only to your VPN IP, thus forcing all traffic to use your VPN or be ignored

Comment: If the dns connection to Google is unencrypted then your isp can read all your traffic to it...

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus I don't use VPN very often on my computer (mainly on my phone). If I set my VPN as the gateway, will I still be able to log in correctly?

Comment: In that case it won't work. It'll only work if you always use your VPN on your computer.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `route -n` when you are connected via network-manager and terminal.

Comment: My bad, it seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug for this issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1211110

Comment: I found this listing as well after I did some more searching. The only problem is that it hasn't been assigned to anyone yet. I hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: @SuperSluether Me too for your part. Good luck ;)
You could make an alias for the connection to ease its use.

Comment: And enjoy the new rep ;)